# What is the difference between $model->getOrigData(); and $model->getData();?

Tags: magento-1.7, model

There are two methods which retrieve model data.

```
$model->getData();
$model->getOrigData();
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between them ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't mean that. so I just wanna clarify confusing areas in magento. Because I have moved this e-commerce platform recently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getOrigData()` returns the data in the object at the time it was initialised/populated.

After the model is initialised you can update that data and `getData()` will return what you currently have in that object.

Have a look at `Varien_Object` (`getOrigData`,`setOrigData`), `grep -R "origData" app/` so you can have a look at what is used.

In EE, it's very useful to log what is changed (**Enterprise_Logging**) module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also found a resource. http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm

Answer (score 15):

This is easiest explained by an example:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123);
$product->getData('something'); // returns "foo"
$product->setData('something', 'bar');
$product->getData('something');     // returns "bar"
$product->getOrigData('something'); // returns "foo"
```

In a nutshell, every model (once loaded) will make a copy of the originally loaded data and store it in `Model_Class::_origData` property. This makes it possible to do optimizations for `_beforeSave` calls so that queries only modify the changed data and not rewrite the same data all the time.

Also, any time you call `setData()` a flag is set that the model has changed data. You can check if a model has changed data by calling `$model->hasDataChanges()`.